# Why does a query run nearly 100 times slower when only changing a WHERE clause value?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(m.p1_elo_one)
FROM belgarath.match_result as m
INNER JOIN belgarath.tournament AS tm ON tm.id_ = m.tournament_id
INNER JOIN belgarath.tour AS tr ON tr.id_ = tm.tour_id
INNER JOIN belgarath.rank AS rk ON rk.id_ = tm.rank_id
INNER JOIN belgarath.round AS rd ON rd.id_ = m.round_id
INNER JOIN belgarath.parameters_match AS pm
    ON pm.tour_id = tm.tour_id
    AND pm.rank_id = tm.rank_id
    AND pm.round_id = m.round_id
INNER JOIN belgarath.surf ON belgarath.surf.id_ = tm.surf
INNER JOIN belgarath.player AS p ON p.id_ = m.p1_id 
WHERE 
    belgarath.surf.surf_std_id = 1
    AND pm.engineer = 1
    AND m.date_time_inferred < "2003-06-01"
    AND m.date_time_inferred > "2000-06-01"
    AND m.p1_elo_one IS NOT NULL
    AND p.name_ NOT LIKE "%/%"
```

The `match_result` table is about 1.4m records and the query runs fine in about 0.4 seconds and returns a count of circa 20k. Great.

However, when I change `belgarath.surf.surf_std_id = 1` to `belgarath.surf.surf_std_id = 2` then the query suddenly takes around 35 seconds to return a count of circa 20k.

This has me stumped as I'm only changing an input variable, nothing else.

Any ideas on where the issue might be?

---

**Edit:**

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `match_result`:

```
'CREATE TABLE `match_result` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time_op_scheduled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time_op_actual` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time_oc_actual` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time_inferred` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tournament_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `round_id` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uncertainty` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `uncertainty_bin` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_pred` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_SD` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `winning_player` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_sets` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `result_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_pinnacle_closing_odds` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_match_data_retrieved` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_elo_all` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_elo_exc_ret_all` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_win_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_h2h_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_win_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_match_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_elo_one` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_elo_exc_ret_one` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_jet_lag` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_fatigue_short_term` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_fatigue_long_term` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_retired_last_match` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_elo_all` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_elo_exc_ret_all` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_win_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_h2h_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_win_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_one_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_one_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_all_time_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_all_surf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_all_time` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_match_all_none` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_elo_one` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_elo_exc_ret_one` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_jet_lag` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_fatigue_short_term` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_fatigue_long_term` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2_retired_last_match` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `engineered` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__completed_sets` (`completed_sets`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__post_match_data_retrieved` (`post_match_data_retrieved`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__date_time_oc_actual` (`date_time_oc_actual`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__tournament_id` (`tournament_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__round_id` (`round_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__player_id_2` (`p2_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__winning_player` (`winning_player`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__result_type_id` (`result_type_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__uncertainty_bin` (`uncertainty_bin`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__date_time_inferred` (`date_time_inferred`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__date_time_op_actual` (`date_time_op_actual`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__player_id_1` (`p1_id`),
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__date_time_op_scheduled` (`date_time_op_scheduled`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `ix_belgarath_match__engineered` (`engineered`),
  CONSTRAINT `match_result__player_1` FOREIGN KEY (`p1_id`) REFERENCES `player` (`id_`),
  CONSTRAINT `match_result__player_2` FOREIGN KEY (`p2_id`) REFERENCES `player` (`id_`),
  CONSTRAINT `match_result__round` FOREIGN KEY (`round_id`) REFERENCES `round` (`id_`),
  CONSTRAINT `match_result__tournament` FOREIGN KEY (`tournament_id`) REFERENCES `tournament` (`id_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1408022 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

`EXPLAIN` for the query:

[image]

Comment: Are any or all of those WHERE clause columns indexed?

Comment: Note that rank is now a reserved word rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier moving forward (amazingly, ROUND is not reserved)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - hey. All the WHERE clause columns are indexed ecept the last two: `m.p1_elo_one` (Float) and `p.name_ ` (VARCHAR)

Comment: @Strawberry - I'd left off `SHOW CREATE TABLE` because there are so many tables and columns. I wondered if the symptom pointed to something obvious? I'll put the `EXPLAIN` up now - that was a new one for me! Thanks for the heads up on `rank` - I'd just noticed it too...

Comment: Hm, I'd amend   `ix_belgarath_match__date_time_inferred` to include `p1_elo_one` - and stick an index on some permutation of (`tour_id,rank_id,round_id,engineer`). But maybe someone else has some better ideas.

Comment: @Strawberry - thanks!. So no improvement on `belgarath.surf.surf_std_id = 1` from the first suggestion. In fact the complete opposite - it now takes the same time as `belgarath.surf.surf_std_id = 2`. That's hopefully progress in narrowing down the problem right? :) On the latter suggestion - I presume I should put that index in the `parameters_match` table? Doing that brings down the problem query time to about 3.5 seconds so definite progress!!

Comment: @Strawberry - found the issue and learnt a big lesson in the process about what to check before posting here. There were a couple of FKs missing from the `tournament` table. Thanks for your help - you put me on the right track!!

Comment: You're welcome (even encouraged) to submit, and then accept, your own answer.